# I'm having trouble with getting Android Studio and gradle to work to make my app onto an android app bundle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm in the process of making a sudoku app, and want to do a closed test through Google play to see how things are going with it, but am having issues. I'm using Livecode to make the actual apk, which seems fine, and one of the settings is to make it for 4 different architectures into the one apk.

As far as I understand it, it's 50mb because it's basically 4 apps in one, and each user will only need one, so the android app bundle will take all the unnecessary code for other architectures and only install what's needed for each user. The followed the tutorials and got AS and gradle up to date (I've got the [latest version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ahmi.jpg) 6.6.1), and imported the apk into AS. However, when I went to make it into a bundle, it gave me an error, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwoy1.jpg), saying that I don't have the latest android gradle plug in

I did some research and found a couple of people who had similar issues, but we're able to force the plug in to use a specific version from the build.gradle file, but I don't have that either, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lQ8n.jpg). The other option people say is to force the version from the settings/project, but I can't find the settings for those when people talk about it. Here's my [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMt9r.jpg) and my [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGz9L.jpg)

The other thing people say is to just close AS and reopen it and it'll automatically ask me to update the plug in, but mine doesn't do that. I'm at a loss here and have no idea how to even get a build.gradle file to edit in the first place.

If anyone has any ideas, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why use gradle, if you have LiveCode?!

Comment: If I choose all the architecture types, it makes a single apk that's 50MB big - as far as I understand, if I upload all of it to Google, users will be downloading a much larger app than needed, whereas if I could get Gradle to work with it, I could make it into an App bundle so Google can handle giving users the appropriate files and making it smaller. I know I can make multiple apk files and upload them as different versions, but it just seems much easier to let Grandle and Google handle it if I could. Am I missing something with how it works though? Because that'd be great if I am!

Comment: I wouldn't bother for 50MB. How much are you going to take off it with gradle? 10MB? 20? Not really an issue for people who have 32GB storage space on their phones (or 128GB, which isn't uncommon these days). It would be different if your app took several GB's, but even then the LiveCode engine would be only a small part of that and you can include all source files as separate files or even install them later on first launch. Oh... wait I guess that's the answer. I"ll post it below.

Comment: With Gradle and app bundling, it would bring it down to ~12MB per app. Considering every other app out there for what I'm doing is 5-10MB max, it seems crazy to have an app 5-10 times the size if I could use Gradle and app bundling to make it a more reasonable size for users

Comment: Don't bother. On my phone, it would still be one of the smallest apps.

Comment: The issue is my target audience aren't necessarily people with fancy new phones and lots of storage. Going from 5MB to 50MB for an app would be a big difference, and for a lot of users that would be a significantly huge increase in app size

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Gradle. First of all, 50MB isn't something to worry about. It isn't worth the hassle. To keep your LiveCode build small, you could follow a few steps.

First check that your build really gets much bigger if you build for multiple architectures. Include your substacks and other files as separate files. Don't make them part of the mainstack. Now, if your source files are 100MB, your build should be x*(the size of the engine) + the size of your other source files, rather than x*(the size of the engine + the size of your source files). Is this true? Then you're done. You can release your app and not worry.

Second, if you still believe there is a problem, you could put your materials on a server and let people download those materials when your app launches for the first time on their phones. That way, you're sure that there is only one copy of your materials on the user's phone. You won't have a copy of your substacks and other source files for every architecture but you will have mutiple engines and only one copy of all other files.

Comment: Hey Mark. So, when I compile the code for each architecture, they each end up being ~12MB. I also checked the apk I made that included all architectures in Android Studio and was able to confirm that each architecture was making up ~25% of the total app size. Secondly, I don't have any extra files (except about 200kb worth of things like text files and a few icons, but nothing major), and no other substacks or anything like that, so there's nothing for users to download after the fact. It just seems silly considering 50MB is 5-10 times the size of other apps on the Play Store

Comment: Hi Mark. [Here's](https://imgur.com/eInhIHL) a test version of the app that I'm in the process of updating to where I've managed to remove a few things to make it more optimised (and added some assets for debugging and testing which won't be in the final version). As you can see in Android Studio, the full apk that LC is making is made up of 4 architectures that are each around 10MB, which is how much each apk is if I make them individually, but when I have all 4 architectures chosen, it's 4 times the size, and 75% of it will be unusable code for users, just taking up space that isn't needed.